# Not getting output field from Python Toolbox?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-toolbox

I can't see output field in my simple tool

```
    def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""

    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
        name="Input Features",
        displayName="Area",
        direction="Input",
        datatype="DEFeatureClass",
        parameterType="Required")

    param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
        name="Output Features",
        displayName="Output",
        direction="Output",
        datatype="DEFeatureClass",
        parameterType="Derived")

    param1.parameterDependencies = [param0.name]
    param1.schema.clone = True

    parameters = [param0, param1]

    return parameters
```

I doesn't pass rest of code (toolbox object ...) because I didn't inject there any changes.

[image]

What can cause this problem? I used *.pyt.

Comment: To qualify as a code snippet that potential answerers can copy/paste to see what you have tried and where you are stuck,  I think you should expand the code presented so that it includes everything in your test Python Toolbox.

Comment: Have you added your parameter to the script tool? It's no good just talking about a 2nd parameter if you haven't added it to the tool in the toolbox.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I think the asker is using a Python Toolbox tool (`*.pyt`) rather than a Python script tool in a standard toolbox (`*.tbx`).

Comment: Sorry guys, I was very tired. I want to read output FIELD not file xD. I hava a problem, beacouse I add seceond filed as Output Field but my arcMap not show me this field.

Comment: Yeah i used *.pyt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [ArcGIS help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/parameter.htm):

> **parameterType**
>
> Can be Required, Optional, or Derived. ***Derived means that the user of
> your tool does not enter a value for the parameter.*** Derived types are
> always output parameters.

Instead use:

```
direction='Output', parameterType='Required'
```